# Prompt dialog in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a small project in c++ and packing it into GUI. The reference source code is [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools) (Download source code - 61.1 Kb)

I want to prompt a dialog window when choose "menu"-"edit"-"parameter setting". I have already draw a dialog like this

[image]

When click "parameter setting"

```
private void menuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (drawArea.GraphicsList.ShowFormParameter(this))
   {
      drawArea.SetDirty();
      drawArea.Refresh();
   }
}


public bool ShowFormParameter(IWin32Window parent)
{
   return true;
}
```

But it does not work, the dialog doesn't show when clicking. How can I realize that?

Comment: Something is badly wrong here... You're talking about creating an MFC application, and you've tagged the question [tag:c++] and [tag:mfc], but the code you've shown is obviously C# and using the WinForms framework. Worse, there's a [tag:c#] tag on the question. So I have no idea what you're actually trying to do. MFC doesn't work with C#. Is the MFC part just a red herring? Are you actually just creating a C# WinForms application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the code you've posted actually shows a dialog. You use the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) member function to do that, but you're not calling that function.

Out of context, I don't really know what the purpose of the `ShowFormParameter` function is. I suppose it's an attempt to modularize the code by placing the code to display the parameters dialog in a single function.

At any rate, you need to write code inside this function to actually show the dialog you created:

```
public bool ShowFormParameter(IWin32Window parent)
{
   // This creates (and automatically disposes of) a new instance of your dialog.
   // NOTE: ParameterDialog should be the name of your form class.
   using (ParameterDialog dlg = new ParameterDialog())
   {
       // Call the ShowDialog member function to display the dialog.
       if (dlg.ShowDialog(parent) == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           // If the user clicked OK when closing the dialog, we want to
           // save its settings and update the display.
           //
           // You need to write code here to save the settings.
           // It appears the caller (menuItem7_Click) is updating the display.
           ... 

           return true;               
       }
   }
   return false;  // the user canceled the dialog, so don't save anything
}
```

Comment: One more wonder want to raise, although it have little relation to the theme. The reference source code demos a drawing tool. So if I draw a rectangle in the draw area, could the parameter of shapes(eg. x,y,width,height in the DrawRectangle.cs) extracted from the code and then displayed in a new dialog?

Comment: @qingyao Use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question. Do be sure to include the code you're talking about in your new question.

Comment: I have asked a new question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334957/extract-and-display-parameter-in-a-dialog-from-c-sharp-winforms)