# Extract and display parameter in a dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a small project and packing it into GUI. The reference source code is [DrawTools(Download source code - 61.1 Kb)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools).

The reference source code demos a drawing tool in C# WinForms.

The function is to draw different figures like rectangle, ellipse, polygon, etc.

I want to use the location and size information of these figures to do further work, so if I draw a rectangle in the draw area, could C# WinForms returns the parameter of this figure(eg. x,y,width,height in the `DrawRectangle.cs`)?

Code as follow:

```
public DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        rectangle.X = x;
        rectangle.Y = y;
        rectangle.Width = width;
        rectangle.Height = height;
        Initialize();
    }
```

Further more, How to get the returned parameters and then displayed in a new dialog?

Comment: Your description says C++, but the tag is C#.  Which is it?

Comment: Did you go through source code?

Comment: @mbeckish I am wondering can the C# winforms return parameters based on my action on the window? So actually it is c# I think.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am a new comer in c# winforms. So my question may be very elementary... I discover there are parameters like"x" "y" "width" and "height" in the reference code, they may the parameters I desire. But I don't know how to get them and display them on a dialog.

Comment: @QingyaoLi - Which part is C++?

Comment: @mbeckish actually question is about c# only, c++ in question is misleading

Comment: @QingyaoLi - If that is the case, please edit your question and remove the reference to C++.

Comment: I have written a program in c++ and want to display it in a graphical interface. SO my problem is mainly about the C# winforms.

Answer (score 0):

when you draw these shapes: rectangle, ellipse, polygon, etc. you are using the location and width and height of them. if you want to save them to an object create one and save them in a list of some other structure...
for example:

```
  List<object> shapes = new List<object>(); 

  private void drawSquare(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
  {
     shapes.Add(new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2));

  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     Graphics g = e.Graphics;

     foreach (var shape in shapes)
     {
        if (shape is Rectangle)
        {
           g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), (Rectangle)shape);
        }
     }
  }
```

this is just a small example, you should check the `OnPaint` method and `Graphics` to get more information on what you can and should do

Answer (score 0):

You can add some event to support notifying what is happening, something like this:

```
public class InitRectangleEventArgs : EventArgs {
   public Rectangle Rectangle {get;set;}
}
public delegate void InitRectangleEventHandler(object sender, InitRectangleEventArgs e);
public event InitRectangleEventHandler InitRectangle;
public DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    rectangle.X = x;
    rectangle.Y = y;
    rectangle.Width = width;
    rectangle.Height = height;
    if(InitRectangle != null) InitRectangle(this, new InitRectangleEventArgs { Rectangle = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height)});
    Initialize();
}
//To use it, just subscribe the event so that you can know the 
//info of the Rectangle everytime it is initialized
InitRectangle += (s,e) => {
  //Get the info from the Rectangle property of e:   e.Rectangle
  //....
};
```